# Is there a cat utility for Apache's avro?

Tags: cat, avro

I'd like to know if there is a 'cat' utility for Apache's binary avro file format?

Something along the lines of zcat, or bzcat for gzip and bzip2 respectively.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [avrocat](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-836) was included in the 1.6.0 release. Look in the scripts/ directory of the Python implementation of Avro.

Answer (score 1):

[fastavro](https://github.com/tebeka/fastavro)

1. `pip install fastavro`
2. `fastavro filename.avro --pretty`